# How can I set a database field to only allow entries up to a certain number?

Tags: postgresql, types

I am setting up a scheduling schema and I have a few tables; the few that are in question are "weekly_schedules", "monthly_schedules", and "quarterly_schedules".

The weekly table has a column titled "day_of_week" - I want to limit what numbers are put in here to a maximum of 7 (as there are only 7 days in a week)

The monthly table has a column titled "day_of_month" - I want to set a max of 31

and quarterly table has 2 columsn titled "month_of_quarter" - limit this to 1-12, and "day_of_month" - limit to 31

Is this possible? or is there a better method of doing this?

Database is postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use **[`CHECK` constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-constraints.html)** for this purpose.

eg. `weekday numeric CHECK (weekday > 7)` (assuming 0-index days)